# How can I stop Google Toolbar offering to translate my app?

Tags: google-translate, google-toolbar

How can I stop Google Toolbar offering to translate my web app?

I've tried adding this tag to the top of every page:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Language" CONTENT="en-GB">
```

but it makes no difference.

I'm developing a web app in ASP.NET which displays a lot of data from various languages - things like names, locations, etc.  If the user has Google Toolbar, it recognises the page variously as Italian, Spanish, etc, depending on exactly which data items they are looking at, and pops up a prompt offering to translate it.

The translation would make no sense in this context since the words which it is recognising are names and so on which are only relevant in the original language.

This is the prompt I'm talking about:[image: google toolbar translation]

---

EDIT: As a user, you can disable this feature entirely:
http://www.google.com/support/toolbar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146786
But there doesn't seem to be any way to mark a page as not suitable for translation by the toolbar.

Comment: Update December 2013: The W3C have published a new article on [Using HTML's translate attribute](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-translate-flag) which reflects the current state in 2013.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

from [Google FAQ](http://www.google.com/help/faq_translation.html#donttrans). Not sure if this works for the toolbar, though...

Comment: Good find - and very interesting. But it doesn't work. I've just tried the meta tag, and also the class names, and it has no effect. I guess it only affects the main web search not the toolbar.

Comment: :( If your toolbar is up-to-date, I think you should tell google that it's broken - they should obey there too ;)

Comment: I tried updating my toolbar, but I was already using the latest.  I guess I will try to file a bug!

Comment: It works for me with regard to the translate built into Chrome.  I don't have Google Toolbar installed.

Comment: This answer is not longer relevant